# Youtube API v3 get videos - PHP

Tags: php, youtube, google-api

I'm trying to get a list of youtube videos while searching on a specific keyword.
I've tried the following tutorial : [Search by keyword](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#search_by_keyword) 
Unfortunatly it doesn't work.

The following error appears on my screen:

```
A service error occurred: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&q=amsterdam&maxResults=20&key=PRIVATEKEY: (403) Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.
```

I have activated the following API's in my console

YouTube Data API v3

YouTube Analytics API

Freebase API

Am i missing some API's?
I've also enabled billing, but it still isn't working.

A little part of my code:

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);

              $youtube = new Google_YouTubeService($client);
    $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
                  'q'           => $_GET['q'],
                  'maxResults'  => $_GET['maxResults'],
));
```

Comment: I have solved the problem, my referer uri's where probably invalid. Removed the uri's in my google console and all URI's are allowed now and its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$DEVELOPER_KEY = '';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);

$youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);

try {
  $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
     'q' => $_GET['q'],
     'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
   ));

$videos = '';
$channels = '';
$playlists = '';

foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
  switch ($searchResult['id']['kind']) {
    case 'youtube#video':
      $videos .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $searchResult['snippet']['title'],
        $searchResult['id']['videoId']);
      break;
    case 'youtube#channel':
      $channels .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $searchResult['snippet']['title'],
        $searchResult['id']['channelId']);
      break;
    case 'youtube#playlist':
      $playlists .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $searchResult['snippet']['title'],
        $searchResult['id']['playlistId']);
      break;
  }
}


echo ($playlists)
```

this will be work